# 0 processes and 1 service

Tags: android, debugging, service, ddms

Any idea why I see in the manage applications "Running" tab, both my application and google maps with "0 processes and 1 service"?  My app has been dying, but not completely and it doesn't restart.  I was trying to connect the DDMS to see what is going on, but no processes show for the device (i have checked that my manifest has debuggable="true").

Comment: Try capturing the logcat immediately after it crashes

Comment: Ah, so that is a large challenge.  I have tried this in the past with no success.  The amount of time it takes for the service to die is variable, and i am not sure how to reproduce the issue.  Part of the issue i think was that i'd let the phone sit connected to Eclipse debugger, but the logcat gets messed up after some time passes so i miss messages.  My attempt to solve this is that i am attmepting to run logcat and save to a 50MB file on the SD card from a terminal on the phone itself.... i'll post any results

Comment: Try running logcat out of a terminal on the host machine ie, 'adb logcat | tee somefile' (linux/osx) or just let 'adb logcat' run on any OS and copy and paste it out of the terminal window.  Of course bugs that don't happen frequently are annoying, maybe you can figure out a way to make it happen faster.

Comment: I knew that it had to have been due to low memory, but i wasn't able to repro before.  I suppose i didn't try hard enough, but i've learned that the Draw Something game makes my phone slow and crash, so i ran that, and now i can reproduce.  Depending on how far i can get on my own, i may open a new item for the actual issue.  As for my question - is 0 processes and 1 service a valid state?  It seems like the service crashes / gets dumped due to memory, then never restarts (even though it says scheduled for restart).

Comment: Another thing that notice in the logs is that when the service is killed due to low memory, you get this entry in the logs: Scheduling restart of crashed service ... in 3140574ms  The number of ms is random, but this is a lot of time.  Anyone know what determines the length of the restart delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is....
A service is not a process, therefore it is valid for a service to be created, but not started.  If the service is not started, then there are 0 processes.
In my particular case, i noticed that the logs stated "Scheduling restart of crashed service".  I assumed that it meant onStart() was going to be called, which is not the case.  Here are two links which helped answer this question:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a9d3c1acbd46e384#

["Scheduling restart of crashed service", but no call to onStart() follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398482/scheduling-restart-of-crashed-service-but-no-call-to-onstart-follows)

Comment: Not quite. Both links indicate that onCreate() is called, which is something that categorically cannot occur unless a process exists.

Comment: Can you edit / correct my comment?  The OS redelivers the intent (if returned in the onStartCommand)  Once this occurs, there is now a new process, is there not?  That is what I am experiencing in my latest tests.